# Trouble passing entire two dimensional array as parameters in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, apply

I am trying to generate divs around each of the elements of a two dimensional array using the methods below. So far the code only outputs the last 3 elements in the array (the 3 elements of third nested array). I am passing the array elements as parameters using .apply. How could I modify this to output each element of the array catArray in order? And why would it only pass the last 3 as it is? Any advice would be appreciated, I am trying to understand this better. I have spent hours on this, hopefully someone can help.

Here is a codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kzEdK

```
function cats(catName, catFur, catEyes) {
  $("#row").html('<div>' + catName + '</div>' + '<div>' + catFur + '</div>' + '<div>' + catEyes + '</div>');
}

var catArray = [
  ["fluffy", "soft", "green"],
  ["mittens", "coarse", "fire"],    
  ["wiskers", "none", "grey"]
];

function catGenerator() {
  for (var i = 0; i < catArray.length; i++) {
  var blah = catArray[i];    
  cats.apply(this, blah);
  }
}

catGenerator();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
function cats(catName, catFur, catEyes) {
  // note the difference (append() instead of html())
  $("#row").append('<div>' + catName + '</div>' + '<div>' + catFur + '</div>' + '<div>' + catEyes + '</div>');
}

function catGenerator() {
  $("#row").html(""); // in case you wish to call catGenerator() multiple times, clear the row before appending to it
  for (var i = 0; i < catArray.length; i++) {
    var blah = catArray[i];    
    cats.apply(this, blah);
  }
}
```

It shows only the last 3 elements because `$("#row").html("...")` *overwrites* the contents of `#row` three times and the value set in the last iteration remains visible. I fixed that by replacing `html()` with `append()`, which does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have $("#row").html() which will replace the markup within the div tag after each iteration. Consider using $("#row").append()

```
function cats(catName, catFur, catEyes) {
  $("#row").append('<div>' + catName + '</div>' + '<div>' + catFur + '</div>' + '<div>' +     catEyes + '</div>');
}

var catArray = [
  ["fluffy", "soft", "green"],
  ["mittens", "coarse", "fire"],    
  ["wiskers", "none", "grey"]
];

function catGenerator() {
  for (var i = 0; i < catArray.length; i++) {
  var blah = catArray[i];    
  cats.apply(this, blah);
  }
}

catGenerator();
```